# Error on Repeated Code Use

Tags: c#, indexof

Can someone explain why I receive a 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element'' error on the third line below? It is the exact same line as line 1, the only thing that has changed is I have modified a field of the data on the item in the list using the index, but the data modified is irrelevant to the search query. There is data in the List at all times.

```
int index = junctions.IndexOf(junctions.First(item => item.coOrds == currentPos));
junctions[index].possibleDir[0] = true;
index = junctions.IndexOf(junctions.First(item => item.coOrds == currentPos));
```

**Extra info**

Not sure if relevant but the coOrds and currentPos fields are `Tuple<int, int>`, possibleDir is a `bool[]`. Junctions is a List of a custom class Junction.

Same problem if I use either of the below other options;

```
var value = junctions.First(item => item.coOrds == currentPos);
var value = junctions.Find(item => item.coOrds == currentPos);
```

**Follow on**

Seems it had to do with the Tuple comparison, the below line works fine. I have no idea why the first line above worked (and still does) but not consistently.

```
index = junctions.IndexOf(junctions.First(item => item.coOrds.Item1 == currentPos.Item1 && item.coOrds.Item2 == currentPos.Item2));
```

Comment: its hard to guess without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), is the list being accessed from multiple threads ? Did you debug the code to confirm that the item you are looking for is on the list ?

Comment: @SelmanGenç No multithreads, not a particularly complex program to be honest. I have debugged in and can see the data in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> The First(IEnumerable) method throws an exception if
>   source contains no elements. To instead return a default value when
>   the source sequence is empty, use the FirstOrDefault method.

Reference link: [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx)

You should use `FirstOrDefault` and check null

Comment: There is data in the List, otherwise the error would have appeared on line 1.

Comment: It doesn't mean `No data in list`. It means `No data matched your condition in list`, and if you are using `First`, it throws `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Upvoted because I'm not quite sure why you were downvoted. This seems like it's actually the solution. Here's an example of what's going on https://dotnetfiddle.net/gYrVJq